# React doesn't properly render div tags based on conditions

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, reactjs

When rendering a list of div tags, if the div was already present in the DOM, when running for the first time, then it gets added with less html attributes.

here is my render method:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
             {renderModel(...)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

And here is the implementation of `renderModel(...)`

```
function renderModel(...) {
    var connections = [];

    // code to come up with the string to compare for

    if (checkString(stringToCheck)) {
        connections.push(renderModel(...));
    } else {
        connections.push(<div onClick={handleClick} value={stringToCheck}>{label}</div>);
    }
    return connections;
}
```

So the `renderModel(...)` will recursively render.

The `checkString(...)` function will tell when to directly print the div, or to recursively look for child nodes (of which, the implementation I have skipped in the code).

There is an array which has some strings which are part of the logic of this function.

Some `div` tags gets printed recursively initially, while others don't. Then based on the user action, strings in the array gets changed. So when the rendering runs for a second time - after strings are changed - then the `div`s which rendered recursively first time needs to be printed without recursion, all goes well, but the `div` tag gets added without the `value` or any other properties in the code.

But it is interesting to note that the `onClick` handle works fine. Only the other properties gets skipped.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you not forget to return the `connections` from the function? Also brackets around `{renderModel(...)}` is not necessary.

Comment: @just-boris sorry, I corrected it. I actually have simplified the actual code above, and missed the return statement.

Comment: your connections are rendered as multiple div elements, react requires 1 root component (eg, a surrounding div). Maybe check into https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.bv153y20f . All these connections can be considered as children of your main rendering component. So maybe make a ConnectionList & ConnectionListItem component, where the render of the connectionListItem component returns null when not available and the div when it is available. Then you can map those children as children of your connectionList component (in the render)

Comment: @Icepickle oops.. again a mistake of overly simplifying the code.

Comment: @manas, the rest of my comment still holds true, you shouldn't let 1 component do both the displaying of the list and displaying the listitems, your listitem is the dumb component, the smart component is the list. Check the url ;)

Comment: @Icepickle is right. Also, when you render a list of components, react requires a unique `key` for each item in the list. Which can get complicated if your recursive function may render a list inside a list..

Comment: going through the docs..

Comment: @wintvelt adding unique keys solved this.

Comment: @Icepickle thanks for the info on dumb/smart components. although not relevant to problem, I found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [wintvelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5358807/wintvelt), adding unique keys to the items in the array solved this.